# Entity Framework 6.x Must specify mapping for all key properties

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, many-to-many, edmx

I am beginning playing with EF 6.x and I've got an annoying issue.

I've designed a database with simple User,Role,Permissions tables each one bond to another with classic many-to-many relation.

EF wants me to create primary keys in indirect tables (UserPermissions etc.)
but also wants me to make some mapping for those Primary Keys but I have no clue why.

Is there something wrong with my design or there Is a workaround to this issue?
Maybe Can I in some way use Unique index instead of Primary Key to satisfy EF?

There you have [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjSWB.png) to make it more clear:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm embarrased that I've not came up to solution earlier.

Just added multicolumn Primary Key on columns referencing direct tables via foreign key.

e.g. `CONSTRAINT pk_IdRole_IdPermission_RolePermissions PRIMARY KEY (IdRole,IdPermission)`